# Updating only duplicate records in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

My table structure is -

```
OBJID || Scheduled_Job_status || Started_On || scheduledJob2Order
```

I have a table which stores the details about scheduled jobs running stats. It references to other tables based on the scheduledJob2Order + started_on time. Due to some bugs, it created multiple records with same started_on time and scheduledJob2Order. Now I'm trying to add a constraint that it should create only 1 record with same Started_on time but before that, I need to make changes to the current duplicate records.

My problem is I can't delete duplicate records but I can only update the already available started_on time. Also, I need to update only the started_on time for 1 record. Let's say I got 3 duplicate records in which I need to update 2 records started_on time but rest 1 must have original started_on.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you delete the duplicate records? If it's because they are referenced in records in other tables, then you need to first change the foreign key values in those records to point to the record you will be keeping. Then, once there are no references to the duplicates, you should be able to delete them with something like:

```sql
    DELETE FROM tablex
    WHERE OBJID NOT IN 
        (SELECT MIN(OBJID)
         FROM tablex
         GROUP BY scheduledJob2Order, Started_On)
```

Again, this assumes you can delete after you clear up the references. If not, you should be able to change the `Started_On` using an `UPDATE` query with a similar `WHERE NOT IN (SELECT MIN(OBJID)` to find them.

**UPDATE:** Based on the OP comments below, here is how to update the `Started_On` column. This will set the date to Jan-1-1900 for any duplicate records:

```sql
    UPDATE tablex SET Started_On = TO_DATE('01/01/1900', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    WHERE OBJID NOT IN 
        (SELECT MIN(OBJID)
         FROM tablex
         GROUP BY scheduledJob2Order, Started_On)
```

Comment: Hi actually other tables will save 18 columns in a normal case but with duplicate records, it saved some column values with one record and some with other record so I can't delete either of the records.

Comment: I even tried to merge the records but I don't have any constraint on which I can delete the extra record. I only see the option to update the started_on time other records that exists more than once

Comment: @SravanB, I would be worried that your data is corrupted. But while tedious, I still think that you should be able to replace the foreign keys with the `MIN(OBJID)` wherever the duplicate records are referenced. But if you are insistent on changing the `Started_On` column, I indicated how above. Note that I "assumed" you wanted to change it to an early date that could be filtered out of new queries, but I'm sure you can change my `SET Started_On` to whatever you want.